# Base Templates are deployed without any language version

Tags: azure, templates, tds

We have very bizare issue with our deployment.
Project contains of multiple templates and we recently (couple of months ago) introduced couple of base templates. 
We have prefixed them with underscore, ex. : `_Breadcrumb`.

We are using Sitecore 8.2 with TDS to generate deployment packages. As a CI/CD we are using Azure DevOps.

Yesterday after deployment to our test environment we have noticed that our site broke.

After some breif investigation we have noticesd that our base templates wre missing English version (item was there but without any language version).

Ony one have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

So aparently we introduced this bug, fixing something else.

To allow automatic creation of content with item names containing non standard characters, we have changed fololowing setting:

`configuration/sitecore/settings/setting[name="ItemNameValidation"]`

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="ItemNameValidation" value="^[\*\$\p{L}\p{N}][\.\s\-\$\p{L}\p{N}]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$"/>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

So we have basically changed a regex from

`^[\w\*\$][\w\.\s\-\$]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$`

to

`^[\p{L}\p{N}\*\$][\p{L}\p{N}\.\s\-\$]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$`

instead of using `\w` we used `\p{L}\p{N}` to allow for 'any kind of letter from any language'.

But we have forgot that `\w` was also including '_' (underscore) character.

This prevented the TDS from publishing the base templates with English language version as all base tempaltes (or Helix 'Interface Templates') are prefixed with underscore.

Hope this will help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's great you resolved the issue. I observed something similar however is due to a TDS bug.

If you are using the Powershell script generated by TDS to deploy the generated WebDeploy packages and the Sitecore items, and TDS version is before 6.0.0.7. Try upgrading it to 6.0.0.7 and above to avoid the issue.